# Multiple WHERE OR Expression in query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here the Query to Select Multiple Expression

```
SELECT * FROM tbProducts WHERE
(PRICE BETWEEN 4590 AND 5100) AND RATING = (SELECT MAX(RATING) FROM tbxProducts) AND 
(PRICE = (SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM tbxProducts))
```

These are the columns from tbProdcts

```
| PRODUCT_NAME | DESCRIPTION | RATING | PRICE |
```

but the problem is that the table cannot display any Items with the range of 4590 up to 5100

And after that. I would select also the max rate of an items and max Price with that Range of Price

how can I do it with the right query?

Thanks in Advanced :)

Comment: ¿Why do you have 2 conditions for price? what you need to do with de max value of price?

Comment: You have subqueries here in your where predicates but they are not correlated with the main query. You probably need to add a where clause to those 2 subqueries so it retrieves the max for a given product.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I would Select the max Value of price because there's a possibility that in every rate of product are the same so I need to select max price on that same rate of products..  @MelgoV

Comment: @Anonymous So you want to find the single item with the highest rating, if there are multiple items with the same highest rating, the one of them with the highest price?

Comment: Absolutely Yes! but on that range that was given on the problem :) @Joachim Isaksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for in a somewhat more straight forward manner.

It will return the item with the highest rating. If there are multiple items with the same highest rating, it will use the highest price as a tie breaker.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM tbProducts 
WHERE price BETWEEN 4590 AND 5100
ORDER BY rating DESC, price DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to limit the output of

```
SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM tbxProducts
```

so something like

```
SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM tbxProducts t where t.PRICE BETWEEN 4590 AND 5100
```